# What type of class to use

Tags: c#, class, static, abstract, public

I am not too familiar with classes and stuff so I am asking for some simple help here.. I've got a lot of database functions which I use a lot so I thought I'd put this into a class which I can call from other classes which require data from the database.

For example I've got a window that outputs a list of people, I've got the same code in the edit person window and I am repeating the same code for both of them.

What class to a I use ? I am very confused. I've implemented it as a static class but I wasn't sure if it was working correctly.

If someone could just give a simple primer on what classes are which I would very much appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure "how to do OO programming" is an appropriate scope for a SO question. (Or that it's something that is sufficiently explained with a Cliff's Notes summary.)

Comment: Sure, how many years do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A static class is basically a dressed up global variable. You don't create instances of a static class. All the methods must be static and if it holds onto any data, the data fields must be static. This means that all code that uses this class will be using the same data.

If your intent is to centralize db access pain points like login and session, a static class might be appropriate. Just always keep in mind that calls from different clients will see the same details from the static class.

A non-static class, or instance, is something that stores different data in each instance.  You have to create an object instance of the class before you can do anything with it. The advantage of creating an object is that each consumer that constructs its own instance is isolated from any other consumers of that class.  If window A constructs an instance of your db class and does operation abc, and window B constructs its own instance of your db class and does operation xyz, abc and xyz will not cross paths - they do not share any data between them.

In general, object instances are usually preferred over global/static classes because the shared nature of static classes creates data dependencies and side effects that the consumer may not be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class like this-

```
     public class DBOperator 
     {
       //Only static methods, so no public constructor
       private DBOperator()
       {
       }

       // static constructor          
       static DBOperator()
       {
          // do initialization stuff
        } 

        // have static functions to operate on your database
        public static int ExecuteNonQuery(string storedProc, params object[]         parameters)
        {}
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put repeated code into a method and call the method from multiple methods.

In regards to the DB class, you could put all your DB code in a class - create an instance of it and call it from within other classes.

The DB class though could end up getting messy itself if you just start "bunging" everything DB related in there.

Read up on OO and look into a more efficient way to design your program.